# How can I save a thread from Go SMS Pro to my SD card?

Tags: sms, sd-card, go-sms

I have tried several things, but haven't found one that works. How can I save a message thread from Go SMS Pro to my SD card?

Answer (score 7):

From the main screen (list of threads), long click on the thread and choose the option to "backup  thread."  This will save the thread to your SD card as an xml file.